# right click menu stucks on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows

If I open a folder with VLC from Total Commander, with Right-Click -> Open with VLC, the selected context item stucks over my screen until restart. How can I remove it, or fix that it wont happen again. Happens in other scenarios as well.. Pretty annoying :(

OS is Windows 7 Ultimate SP1

[image]

Comment: Change screen resolution, then return to the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

- Open up task manager (CTRL+SHIFT+ESC)
- Go to the 'Processes' tab
- Select Explorer.exe and end the process
- Click file, then new task.
- Type Explorer.exe and click OK.
- That will make the message disappear.

This looks like explorer crashed at some point, just restarting the main resource will most likely resolve this.

Comment: did it, its still there :(